# Asp.net Core Not Responds When A Request Is made from postman

Tags: asp.net, api, asp.net-core, postman

Right now I'm totally confused why my application is not working. I mean when I send a request from postman or any other api test tool, my backend receives that request and stores the data into the database but does not give any response back. Here is the code.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> AddClass([FromBody] Class cls)
{
    try
    {
        await _context.Classes.AddAsync(cls);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return Ok(cls);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

        return BadRequest("Something Went Wrong");
    }
}
```

But when I remove the

```
await _context.Classes.AddAsync(cls);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

from the controller method then it gives back response to postman or any other api testing too.
Here is my Class Code.

```
public class Class
{
    [Key]
    public int ClassId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string ClassName { get; set; }


    public virtual ICollection<ClassSaction> ClassSactions { get; set; }
    public Class()
    {
        ClassSactions = new Collection<ClassSaction>();
    }

}
```

Here is my ClassSactions Code

```
public class ClassSaction
{
    [Key]
    public int ClassSactionId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(" Class")]
    public int ClassId { get; set; }
    public virtual Class Class { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Saction")]
    public int SactionId { get; set; }
    public virtual Saction Saction { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Enrolment> Enrolments { get; set; }

    public ClassSaction()
    {
        Enrolments = new Collection<Enrolment>();
    }
}
```

And here is my request body (which I send via postman or any other api testing tool.

```
{
    "classId": 0,
    "className": "One Game",
    "classSactions": [
        {
            "SactionId": 1,

        },
        {
            "SactionId": 3
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, there's not enough here to help you. You'll need to investigate this further on your own. In general, it seems like something is getting stuck when working with your database. The `await` keyword holds until the operation completes, and since no response is ever being returned, it seems the operation is not completing. It's odd that stuff is actually happening still on the database, but perhaps not everything is actually completing there. I'd look at the connection between your app and database.

Comment: Seems your controller action is accepting get requests and you are sending a payload in the body. This is only possible on Post requests

Comment: what is it you're expecting back? The number of rows affected? An error caught in the catch and logged? You're returning the original object, i am assuming that is simply not happening?

Would suggest you step through both awaits if possible or at least log the output to understand where it's getting stuck

Comment: Hi MrKobayashi I want to get the same object back.(It stores the data in database tables too.) But I'm unable to do that.
But when I tried to convert this object to an DTO, it is giving me that DTO with all the values.Any Idea why it is not working properly with the object?